# Sort results in elasticsearch based on a condition

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

My document format is like this:

```
{
    "house_id":123
    "address":{"city":"bangalore"},
    ...
}
```

If I query with city="bangalore", I would like to return all results (not just houses with city=bangalore), and sort the results in such a  way that houses with city=bangalore should be on top.

I am exploring the script_score attribute:

```
sort:[{
  "_script": {
    "type": "number",
    "script": "doc['address.city']=CITY",
      "params": {
        "CITY": "bangalore"
      }
    ,"order": "asc"
  }
}]
```

Unfortunately, dynamic scripting is disabled on AWS Elasticsearch which is what I have to use for now. Is there an alternative solution for this problem without using script?

Comment: Have you tried using a `bool` query and `boost` option?

Comment: Yes I ended up doing something like that